# Doxygen STL support using dot graphs

Tags: c++, stl, fortran, doxygen

I'm working on documenting a legacy c++/fortran mixed code using doxygen (version 1.8.0 on a xubuntu 12.04 machine).  My dot_graphs, call graphs, and caller graphs are working properly except when the stl std::vector class is being used.

I have some class foo which needs to contain a vector of another class bar.

```
class foo
{
  //What i'd like to do (1)
  std::vector<bar> d_bars
  //What works (2)
  bar* d_bars
};
class bar
{
  SOME_FUNCTION();
}
```

The bar class contains a variety of functions such as "SOME_FUNCTION()".  When a function within the foo class calls SOME_FUNCTION:`d_bars[i].SOME_FUNCTION();` the caller graph is generated only when d_bars is declared in the second way.  This doesn't work with the current code and need to work while being declared in the first method using the stl vector class.

I already have `BUILTIN_STL_SUPPORT    = YES`.  I know my code isn't perfect above.  I hope you can catch the drift.  My code is quite huge, so I tried to simplify it.

Answer (score 1):

You should have the option `BUILTIN_STL_SUPPORT` turned on.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if what this will help but anyway, who knows.

I've been having exactly the same problem as you have: I have two classes and one of them has a vector of the other class. Even worse, I was generating shared_pointers and later creating vectors of that.

The only solution I had to this, was using sed.. yes, really... For example:

```
class A
{
public:
    A() {};
    ~A() {};
    DoSomeThingA(){
        AA_ = 0;
    };
private:
    int AA_;
};

class B
{
public:
    B() {};
    ~B(){};
    DoSomeThingB(){
        for (size_t i = 0; i < VecA_.size(); i++)
        {
            VecA_[i]->DoSomeThingA();
        }
    };
private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> VecA_;
};
```

I changed it using sed (`sed -e 's/VecA_\[i\]-^>/VecA_\./; s/std::vector^<std::shared_ptr^<A^>^>/A/'`) (I use "^" because I am on windows and that is the escape character that worked for ">"), obtaining:

```
class A
{
public:
    A() {};
    ~A() {};
    DoSomeThingA(){
        AA_ = 0;
    };
private:
    int AA_;
};

class B
{
public:
    B() {};
    ~B(){};
    DoSomeThingB(){
        for (size_t i = 0; i < VecA_.size(); i++)
        {
            VecA_.DoSomeThingA();
        }
    };
private:
    A VecA_;
};
```

Finally, I configured doxygen with:

INPUT_FILTER = `sed -e 's/VecA_\[i\]-^>/VecA_\./; s/std::vector^<std::shared_ptr^<A^>^>/A/'`

FILTER_SOURCE_FILES = yes

SOURCE_BROWSER = yes

VERBATIM_HEADERS = no

Tedious? yes, of course... But it works for me and this is the only way that I could make this work!

Hope it helps